# Qual a melhor forma de atualizar inputs alternadamente

Tags: mysql

Possuo alguns inputs, contudo só devo atualizar os campos que foram preenchidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Por exemplo**:

1. Logotipo e Certificado Digital ficaram em branco. O UPDATE não deve
   ocorrer para esses campos.
2. Logotipo e Senha ficaram em branco. O UPDATE não deve ocorrer para
   esses campos.
3. E assim, por diante.

Ou seja, teria que criar todas combinações de *queries* possíveis? Ou há uma melhor maneira de tratar isso?

Comment: Há uma melhor maneira de tratar isso. Você pode filtrar os dados de `$_POST` e criar a consulta SQL com base nos valores que permaneceram.

Comment: Certo, mas como montaria essa consulta sem gerar uma `query` para cada `if`? @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos considerar que quando seu formulário é submetido, os seguintes valores chegam ao PHP:

```
$_POST = [
    "ambiente" => "Novo ambiente",
    "logotipo" => "",
    "certificado" => "",
    "senha" => "Nova senha"
];
```

De forma simples, você consegue remover os valores nulos da lista utilizando a função [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php).

```
$data = array_filter($_POST);
```

Isso retornará o *array*:

```
Array
(
    [ambiente] => Novo ambiente
    [senha] => Nova senha
)
```

Para construir a consulta SQL, isto é, colocar no formato `$key=$value`, podemos utilizar a função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) em conjunto com a função [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php):

```
$fields = array_map(function ($value, $key) {
    return sprintf("`%s`='%s'", $key, $value);
}, $data, array_keys($data));
```

Isso irá passar o par valor/chave para a função anônima, que retorna o formato desejado. Assim, o *array* que teremos com isso será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => `ambiente`='Novo ambiente'
    [1] => `senha`='Nova senha'
)
```

Podemos juntar os valores utilizando a função [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) e já construir a consulta final:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `tabela` SET %s WHERE `id`=%d", implode(",", $fields), $id);
```

Se exibir o resultado, será:

```
UPDATE `tabela` SET `ambiente`='Novo ambiente',`senha`='Nova senha' WHERE `id`=1
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/LSIakm).

Perceba que se, por exemplo, apenas o campo logotipo foi preenchido, o resultado será:

```
UPDATE `tabela` SET `logotipo`='Novo logotipo' WHERE `id`=1
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/nEkYJ0).

---

Para utilizar o PDO junto com o `bindValue` a lógica é basicamente a mesma. Você constrói a consulta da mesma forma, mas no lugar do valor, você insere o ponto de interrogação:

```
$_POST = [
    "ambiente" => "Novo ambiente",
    "logotipo" => "",
    "certificado" => "",
    "senha" => "Nova senha"
];

$id = 1;

$data = array_filter($_POST);

$fields = array_map(function ($key) {
    return sprintf("`%s`=?", $key);
}, array_keys($data));

$query = sprintf("UPDATE `tabela` SET %s WHERE `id`=%d", implode(",", $fields), $id);

echo $query;
```

Isso gerará uma consulta como:

```
UPDATE `tabela` SET `ambiente`=?,`senha`=? WHERE `id`=1
```

Para executar o *bind* dos valores, basta percorrer os valores:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

foreach (array_values($data) as $i => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue($i+1, $value);
}
```

Gerando, assim, as chamadas:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, 'Novo ambiente');
$stmt->bindParam(2, 'Nova senha');
```

Comment: Bela resposta @AndersonCarlosWoss, bem explicativa e objetiva. Se não for pedir muito, como ficaria utilizando **PDO**?

Comment: @luccasrodrigo Você diz utilizando o `bindParam`?

Comment: Sim @AndersonCarlosWoss. Se puder editar a resposta e acrescentar como **Bônus**, ficaria muito grato rsrs.

Comment: @luccasrodrigo adicionei ao final da resposta. Veja se ficou claro e se funciona :D

Comment: Anderson, tem um detalhe, o array `$fields` é gerado com base no `input name`, que ocasiona incompatibilidade com o nome das colunas no banco. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @luccasrodrigo, basta você renomear os campos dos formulários com os nomes das colunas. Você quer fazer algo mais prático, mas magia ainda não está nas minhas competências :D

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63562/discussion-between-luccasrodrigo-and-anderson-carlos-woss).